# how to increase size of UICollectionViewCell when user is typing in UITextView inside cell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

I have searched a lot everywhere, nothing really helped me or it is in objective-c that also doesn't work.

Any guide will be appreciated. Or if someone needs more detail of requirements I can provide that too, just ask in the comment. However, I believe that the heading of the post is pretty self explanatory.

If someone knows the already answered and working post please guide me over there. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to increase collectionView cell size when typing in textView. Also are you increasing size of textView for nextline?

Comment: Yes I am increasing the size of textView using NSLayoutConstraint. TextView is increasing its size on incrementing lines number. But textView go out of CollectionViewCells bounds. If I anchor the botomAnchor of textView to bottomAnchor of textView then nothing happens. Only size of textView increases upto the remaining area of below the textView.